# Why do some commands show output as 'Running in <id>' followed by 'Removing intermediate container <id>', where as some commands dont?

Tags: docker, docker-image

During docker build, some commands (example: RUN, ENV, WORKDIR, LABEL) return following message: `Running in <id>` followed by `Removing intermediate container <id>`

Where as some commands (example: ADD, FROM, COPY) don't return either running or removing message.

Why do some commands show output as 'Running in ' followed by 'Removing intermediate container ', where as some commands dont? What is the concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a practical matter, it doesn't matter much to you whether an individual Dockerfile step runs in a container or not.  The intermediate layer image IDs are occasionally useful for debugging, but I don't think I've ever used the per-step container IDs for anything.

Of the three commands you list, none of them "run code".  `FROM` just sets the image that the next step will start from; `COPY` and `ADD` inject files into the container filesystem and directly create a layer.  Those don't need to create containers.

I don't know off hand why the other non-`RUN` commands would run in a container.  I ran across [a proposed GitHub PR](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37204) to make `ENV` not use a container.  This would make these commands run a tiny little bit faster, but otherwise you wouldn't notice any difference one way or the other.

Comment: Are they image ids or container ids?

Comment: The messages you quote are container IDs.  You should also see lines like `---> <id>` which are image IDs and should get created for both "kinds" of commands.  (You can `docker run --rm -it <id> /bin/sh` to debug the output of a single Dockerfile step given the image ID, but you can't do anything with the container.)